# How to display roles of the user logged in a select box, in Grails

Tags: grails

I have a user with multiple roles, I want to display his available roles in a dropdown in the header. One way is to write my own custom tag, but is there anyother easy way to do that.

Comment: are using Spring Security Core?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a [custom tag library](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.3%20Tag%20Libraries):

```
class RolesTagLib {
    static namespace = 'my'

    def springSecurityService

    def currentUserRoleSelect = { attrs ->
        def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        def roles = UserRole.findAllByUser(user).collect { it.role } as Set
        attrs.from = roles
        attrs.optionKey = attrs.optionKey ?: 'id'
        attrs.optionValue = attrs.optionValue ?: 'authority'
        out << g.select(attrs)
    }
}
```

And then in your GSP:

```
<my:currentUserRoleSelect name="role"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<g:select>` tag, using `from="${yourPrincipal.roles}` and setting a property to be displayed. More in the official docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html

Comment: how to get the principal from?

Comment: are you using Spring Security to handle users?

Comment: My question is in GSP, its easy in controllers, but I want to show the list of roles in a view. Yes I am using Spring Security

Comment: And I want to show that in a select box so that I can switch between roles

Comment: You should not fetch the principal in the view. You would do better passing the roles from the controller to the view. So, if you know how to get them in the controller, just pass it to the `render` method, inside the model. Then, in the view, put the list of roles inside the "from" tag property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it.  Somewhere, have this method available.

```
def getRoleMap(userInstance) {
    List roles = Role.list()
    roles.sort { r1, r2 ->
      r1.authority <=> r2.authority
    }
    Set userRoleNames = []
    if (userInstance.id) {
      for (role in userInstance.authorities) {
        userRoleNames << role.authority
      }
    }
    LinkedHashMap<Role, Boolean> roleMap = [:]
    for (role in roles) {
      roleMap[(role)] = userRoleNames.contains(role.authority)
    }

    return roleMap

}
```

Then call this method and forward it on to the view as [roleMap:roleMap]

Your view looks like this..

```
<div class='role-map' style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow:auto;border: 1px solid black">
  <g:each in="${roleMap}">
    <div>
      <g:checkBox name="userRoles" value="${it.key.authority}" checked="${it.value}"/>
      ${it.key.authority.encodeAsHTML()}
    </div>
  </g:each>
</div>
```

Then when a user is saved, you can do the following:

```
UserRole.removeAll(user)
params.userRoles.roleAuthorities.each { roleAuthority ->
  UserRole.create(user, Role.findByAuthority(roleAuthority))
}
```